# Oracle REGEXP_LIKE constraint with OR operator

Tags: oracle

I want to create the constraint which will check the format of PostalCode which can be A1A-1A1 or 11111. And I have the command like this

Check (REGEXP_LIKE (PostalCode, '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]-[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]' || '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'))

But that command doesn't work. How can I modify that command?

Comment: Please edit your question to conform to the [mcve]. Welcome to Stack Overflow, recommended reading [ask].

Comment: Note that in Oracle SQL, `||` is a string concatenation operator, not an "or" operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your format is like AAA-AAA or 111-111 or 11111. If not then change the expression below(it is self explanatory).

```
          REGEXP_LIKE (PostalCode, '[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]-[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]') 
          or REGEXP_LIKE (PostalCode,'[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```

Note: But from this, you will also get codes where there are extra characters in it, like AAA-AAAAAA or 11111111. To check for these also, you need to use length too.

```
          (REGEXP_LIKE (PostalCode, '[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]-[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]') 
     and length(PostalCode) =7) 
          or ( REGEXP_LIKE (PostalCode,'[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')  
     and length(PostalCode) =5)
```

Comment: Thank Utsav. Actually I just want to check A1A-1A1 and 11111 format, so REGEXP_LIKE (PostalCode, '[A-Z][0-9][A-Z]-[0-9][A-Z][0-9]') 
          or REGEXP_LIKE (PostalCode,'[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]') 
is the good way to do that :D